# Selenium Java | Trouble finding/clicking button

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to use Selenium in order to open a HTML page and click a button.
The HTML I get back is:

```
<html>
<head> 
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:5050/style.css"> 
  <title>Test</title> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
   <div class="btn-container"> 
    <button class="btn-orange" id="successButton" name="Success" value="Success"> Success </button> 
    <button class="btn-orange" id="failButton" name="Fail" value="Fail"></button> Fail  
   </div> 
  </div>
  <footer class="footer" align="center">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="clearfix">
     <div class="cards pull-left">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </footer> 
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to click the `successButton` but it does not seem to work, I try to access via its id.

Here is the line I use to `click`:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("successButton")).click();
```

And here's my entire function:

```
  public void openTheHtmlPageAndClickButton(
                                String pageUrl,
                                String SiteUrl,
                                String buttonValue) {

        String lastUrl = null;
        boolean timeout = true;

        for (int tryNumber = 1; tryNumber <= 5 && timeout; tryNumber++) {
            WebDriver driver = null;
            try {
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
                System.out.println("Selenium open: " + pageUrl);
                driver.get(pageUrl);
                int i = 0;
                Alert alert;

                while (i++ < 30) {
                    try {
                        alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
                        if (alert != null) {
                            alert.accept();
                        }
                    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {

                    }
                    String currentUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
                    driver.findElement(By.id("successButton")).click();
                    if (!currentUrl.equals(lastUrl)) {
                        System.out.println("currentUrl: " + currentUrl);
                        lastUrl = currentUrl;
                        if (currentUrl.startsWith(SiteUrl)) {
                            timeout = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                            Assert.fail();
                        }
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Selenium exception: " + e.toString());
            } finally {
                if (driver == null) {
                    Assert.fail("Cannot open web driver, probably Selenium docker is down");
                } else {
                    if (timeout) {
                        System.out.println("Page got timeout: page source: " + driver.getPageSource());
                        if (tryNumber == 5) {
                            Assert.fail("Page got timeout 3 times!!!");
                        }
                    }
                    driver.quit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please advise on what am I doing wrong.

Comment: The code looks fine.Debug and see,There is a change that the element might not loaded at the time of `click()`.So use `element.isDisplayed()` to make sure that the element is visible.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: @JeffC, it's not my first question here, but I wanted to provide as much details as possible, as it's my fist time working with selenium.

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: Yes, please tell us how it doesn't work.  are you getting an error?

Comment: @SudhaVelan, apparently the button did not appear when I tried to 'click' it.
Changed the timeout slightly and issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the button did not appear when I tried to 'click' it. Changed the timeout slightly and issue was resolved.